# Segmentation Fault (11) Error when using long variable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have encountered seg fault in the following code. Can anyone help me correct it? The array size should be enough and I am not accessing it out of bound.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    long L,N;
    long sAni[1000], tAni[1000];
    cin >> L;
    cin >> N;
    bool occupied[L+1] = {};

    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> sAni[i] >> tAni[i];
    }

    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (long j = sAni[i]; j <= tAni[i]; j++) {
            occupied[j] = 1;
        }
    }

    long count,max = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i <= L; i++) {
        if (occupied[i] == 0) { // Seg fault here
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << max;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long L; ...bool occupied[L+1] = {};` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a variable.  Use `std::vector<bool> occupied(L + 1);` instead.

Comment: How sure are you that `j` is a valid index in `occupied[j] = 1;`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce segfault, atleast not with online compiler: http://cpp.sh/4ncls

Comment: Does it crash for all inputs? Are you absolutely sure that all `sAni` and `tAni` are `<= L`, and that all inputs succeed?

Comment: What are the values of `L` and `N` that duplicate the error?  Next time, please just hard-code these values into the program instead of using `cin`.

Comment: Lots or room for death in there. `L` large enough for `occupied` to exceed the stack is an easy possibility. So is `N` > 1000.

Comment: - The first line contains one integer L (1 <= L <= 10^9) that represents the length of the river.

- The second line contains an integer N (1 <= N <= 100000) that represents the number of animals.

- Following are N lines. Each line contains two integers s and t (0 <= s < t <= L) that represent the river segment occupied by one animal.

Comment: @GraysonHo -- Please state the actual value of `L` and the actual value of `N`.  Don't describe what they mean.  Also, the comments basically describe what you could do yourself to debug your code.  You can have potentially out-of-bounds accesses, but you make no effort in testing for this.  You also use non-standard array syntax instead of using standard and more safe `std::vector`, that will not blow out the stack if `L` is large.

Comment: @StefanR Did you missed this warning: *"27:10: warning: 'count' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]"* ;) ?

Comment: Sure did miss that :) @Bob__ I tried this really quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First of all we can't initialise a variable-sized array.*

I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve with this piece of code, but I see where the problem is.

For the below Sample Input:

```
5
2
10 20
30 40
```

L -> 5

N -> 2

sAni[0] -> 10, tAni[0] -> 20

sAni[1] -> 30, tAni[1] -> 40

And at below lines of code,

```
for (long j = sAni[i]; j <= tAni[i]; j++) {
    occupied[j] = 1;
}
```

j will be 10, but "occupied" array has size only L + 1 i.e 6(5 + 1) and you are **trying to access  occupied[10]** which causes segmentation fault.

> Please take care when you declare Arrays